# Disable Touchpad while writing is not working in Ubuntu GNOME 20.04

Tags: gnome, xorg, touchpad, 20.04, synaptics

I recently upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04. I noticed that the *Disable Touchpad While Writing* setting doesn't work in GNOME desktop environment. It is "on" in Tweaks, but no change. My keyboard is relatively small, and when I type my palm touches the touchpad and the cursor goes all over the screen. Both  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and xserver-xorg-input-libinput are installed. What else can I do?

```
$ apt search synaptic
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
apt-cacher/focal,focal 1.7.20.1 all
  Caching proxy server for Debian/Ubuntu/Devuan software repositories

muon/focal 4:5.8.0-1ubuntu5 amd64
  graphical package manager

packagekit/focal-updates,now 1.13-2ubuntu21 amd64 [installed]
  Provides a package management service

steam-installer/focal,focal,now 1.0.0.61-2ubuntu3 all
  Installer for Valve's Steam digital software delivery system

synaptic/focal,now 0.84.6ubuntu5 amd64 [installed]
  Graphical package manager

xserver-xorg-input-libinput/focal,now 0.29.0-1 amd64 [installed]
  X.Org X server -- libinput input driver

xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/focal,now 1.9.1-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
  Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server

xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev-hwe-18.04/focal-updates,focal-updates 3:14.5 amd64
  Transitional package for xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev-hwe-18.04

xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
  Transitional package for xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04
```